# Eclipse suddenly takes 5+ minutes to start

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm using Eclipse Galileo (v3.51). All of a sudden, after weeks of it starting up in about 30 seconds or so it's taking 5+ minutes. The message it hangs on org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you made any notable changes?

Comment: I suppose "Use a different editor" isn't the sort of suggestion you're looking for? :-)

Comment: Maybe your workspace metadata got corrupted. Try starting eclipse with the '-clean' argument to start with clean workspace metadata.

Comment: I tried running with the '-clean' flag but it didn't help. I've switched to using MyEclipse for now, pointed it to the same workspace and had no problems with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out something got trashed in my workspace metadata. Once I cleared that (and lost all my workspace settings), everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Which flavor of Eclipse are you using?

I have had bad experiences (like yours) with some plugin combinations -- especially [Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) combined with the [Maven Eclipse Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/).

Comment: Yeap, it could be a plug-in you installed. Try uninstalling any recent plugins.

Comment: No recent plugins. I tried starting off with the Java bundle of Eclipse (without the j2ee plugins), then installed the j2ee components from the udpate site. As soon as they were installed, startup was again crawling slow.

Answer (score 1):

I saw in your answer that your workspace metadata was corrupted.  You may want to consider [running Eclipse with the -clean flag occasionally](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61566.html).  I've been doing that and it always runs well.

Comment: I had tried this, but the -clean setting didn't do anything to fix my problem, I had to delete the metadata folder manually.